# DB creation in Realm-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm an newbie in ios programming. I'll use swift and realm for my app. But I'm not getting how'll I create an DB and table in Realm.

I'm studying [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/) and [realm.io](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).
But here nothing is so much clear to me. I've placed

```
1) realm.framework
```

under project's general tab's embedded binaries section. Now what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `Cocoapods` to install `Realm`? Then you can easily do a `import RealmSwift` in your file and use it, the `Cocoapods` will do like almost all of the library integration for you

Comment: I've no idea on Cocoapods. then I'm studying on it.

Comment: Its very easy to use it :D try give it a read and save many times of manually download and integrate library

Comment: see this once https://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, have checked all this on realm...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this steps https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#prerequisites
But I will advise you, as others have mention to use dependency manager such as cocoa pods. Save you a lot of headaches

https://cocoapods.org